# Counting up and down sequentially using loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a test that needs to plug in values from a list to a peripheral going forwards then backwards sequentially without breaking the loop. here is the structure I need to modify:

```
exampleList = [5 10 60 9 3]

for i, listValue in enumerate(exampleList):
    self.log += 'Status: iteration {0}, sending {1}\n'.format(i, listValue)
    self.device.writeToPeripheral(listValue)
    ...
```

I am trying to essentially write `[5 10 60 9 3 3 9 60 10 5]` (single or extra middle value doesn't matter) to an external device. Changing the list contents will mess up critical objects elsewhere in the environment for different tests. Is there a creative way in python to structure the loop to iterate going up the list, then back down immediately after? I could simply put this in a function and reverse the list after the first call, but I would like to avoid this approach if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to append the reversed list when iterating:

```
for i, list_value in enumerate(exampleList + exampleList[::-1]):
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) like:

**Code:**

```
import itertools as it

exampleList = [5, 10, 60, 9, 3]
forward_back = it.chain(exampleList, reversed(exampleList))

for i, list_value in enumerate(forward_back):
    print i, list_value
```

**Results:**

```
0 5
1 10
2 60
3 9
4 3
5 3
6 9
7 60
8 10
9 5
```